# React Component gets render before store updates

Tags: reactjs, redux, onclick, rendering

I have a component called AlbumCard.js.
In my AlbumList.js component I'm mapping through an Array and creating multiple AlbumCards components. Each AlbumCard has it its own id (it is the data.id of the album basically)

**It should be possible to click on one AlbumCard and get to the next page, where you can see the whole AlbumCard with much more information (passing the data to the next component).**

My Idea is, by  clicking on one AlbumCard, to get the id( data.id), make a get request with that id( data.id), store the returning data in my redux store and  display that in my next component (AbumPage.js).
Unfortunately, that component gets rendered before my state updates.
So I am getting an undefined error the first time I go to that page. If I refresh everything is working because the data is  already there.
I am also using an asnyc onClick function inside the AlbumCard component. (I did not know how to build an onClick function which is getting the id(data.id) of that component, outside that component).

I tried conditinal rendering as well, but is not helping)

**AlbumCard.js**

```
function AlbumCard({ url, albumname, onClick }) {
 // I am passing the onClick handler as a prop
 // My first idea, was to give the div.id the value of the album.id aka data.id as a prop, but I did not know how to get that data later (id = {data.id}) 

  return (
    <>
      <div className='dark:bg-gray-900 sm:m-2 sm:w-40 w-24 m-1 transition duration-200 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md'>
        <div onClick={onClick} id='hi' className='group relative rounded-lg'>
```

**AlbumList.js**

```
 function AlbumList(props) {
const onClick = (event) => {// not working 
    props.fetchAlbum(event.target.id) // not working 
  }

  return (
    <section className='sm:flex sm:justify-between sm:flex-nowrap grid grid-cols-3'>
      {view === 'noSearch' ? (
        <>
          {newreleases.slice(0, 5).map((data) => (
            <AlbumCard
              url={data.images[0].url}
              key={data.id}
              id={data.id}
              albumname={data.name}
              onClick={async () =>
                props.fetchAlbum(data.id) && (await history.push('/home/album'))
              }
            />
          ))}
        </>
```

**fetchAlbum function**

```
export const fetchAlbum = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_ALBUM_PENDING,
  })
  await saxios
    .get(`/albums/${id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data)
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ALBUM_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    })

    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ALBUM_ERROR,
      })
    })
}
```

**AlbumPage.js**

```
    function AlbumPage(props) {
      const album = useSelector((state) => state.album.currentAlbum) // getting called, before 
          the state updates

...

return (
   <img className=' w-full' src={album?.images[0]?.url} alt='..' />) // I am getting an undefined error
```

Comment: You are dispatching `FETCH_ALBUM_PENDING` before api call so it is better to use value from that and show some loader in `AlbumPage` if api is fetching data.

Comment: do you mean to make a loader, while FETCH_ALBUM_PENDING is true ?

Comment: Yes, I meant to show loader while FETCH_ALBUM_PENDING is true. It's most preferable approach.

Comment: {fetchAlbumPending ? (
        <div>Loader</div>
      ) : ( <img className=' w-full' src={album?.images[0]?.url} alt='..' />) awesome that is working thank you !!

Comment: Do you know, how I can get the data.id in a proper way. So that I do not have to make an onClick inside the component ?

Comment: I did not understand this ` how I can get the data.id in a proper way`  where do you want `data.id`?

Comment: Basically, I am making the onClick function inside the component. But I would like to write the onClick function outside the component.  Example:  const onClick = () => { .... props.fetchAlbum} ......   return ( <AlbumCard onClick={onClick} /> . I have written that in AlbumList.js you can see it there :D

Comment: You can also access the history in your redux, and change history after the fetch and setting the data. The history state is mutable data that is the same for everyone, at least the part that allows you to navigate between routes. This way the page is loaded after the API fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AlbumList.js`, you need to call `onClick` function like below:-

```
 function AlbumList(props) {
const onAlbumCardClick = (dataId) => { 
    props.fetchAlbum(dataId)
    history.push('/home/album')
  }

  return (
    <section className='sm:flex sm:justify-between sm:flex-nowrap grid grid-cols-3'>
      {view === 'noSearch' ? (
        <>
          {newreleases.slice(0, 5).map((data) => (
            <AlbumCard
              url={data.images[0].url}
              key={data.id}
              id={data.id}
              albumname={data.name}
              onClick={() => onAlbumCardClick(data.id)}
            />
          ))}
        </>
```

And based on `FETCH_ALBUM_PENDING` value you can show loader in `AlbumPage` like below:-

```
return (
  <div>
    {fetchAlbumPending ?  <div>Loader</div>  :  <img className=' w-full' src={album?.images[0]?.url} alt='..' />
  </div>
)
```